# Post values in URL are not set because of special characters in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I'm trying to pass a string with special characters to your web api but is giving error.

Below the line where I pass the values ​​pro web api:

```
            string listaParcelaSeparadoVirgula = null;

            foreach (var item in listaParcelas)
            {
                listaParcelaSeparadoVirgula = listaParcelaSeparadoVirgula + ";;" + item;
            }

            var result = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(listaParcelaSeparadoVirgula);

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/LancamentoReceitaDespesa/AddLancamentoParcelar/" + result, lancamentoReceitaDespesa).Result;
```

the result is a string variable with values ​​separated by ";;". Below the contents of the string:

```
 ";;aaaaa 1/2||10/01/2014|100,00||;;aaaaa 2/2||10/02/2014|100,00||"
```

with UrlEncode:

```
"%3b%3baaaaa+1%2f2%7c%7c10%2f01%2f2014%7c100%2c00%7c%7c%3b%3baaaaa+2%2f2%7c%7c10%2f02%2f2014%7c100%2c00%7c%7c"
```

Error:

{"Error while copying content to a stream."}

How can I pass these values ​​pro web api?

Comment: Why are you passing the value in the URL and in the body?  Is that really necessary?  I don't think it is the URI that is complaining, it is the JSON.Net serialization that is having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could try encode value with base64 since in url you could have special symbols

```
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
 var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/LancamentoReceitaDespesa/AddLancamentoParcelar/" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes), lancamentoReceitaDespesa).Result;
```

then in web

```
public void AddLancamentoParcelar(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

I am not sure if its the best solution but as you could have any symbol in url then its could be an solution.